# Datepicker in EditText is having error

Tags: android, date

I'm having problem with this set of code.
I got this set of code from the user and edited it in my own code.

I don't know what is modifiedDoctor/ i don't know what should I change it to.
Can someone help me?
PLEASE!

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   // TableLayout tablelayout_Log = null;
    Button saveButton = null;
    Button cancelButton = null;
   // Button searchButton = null;
    EditText dateEdit; 
    EditText priceEdit;
    EditText pumpEdit;
    TextView costView;
    EditText odometerEdit;
    TextView fconView;
     TextWatcher textWatcher;
     String priceEditStr ="",pumpEditStr="";
     String  odmEditStr = "";
     String lastOdm="";
double result;
double resultCon;




    public boolean isNumeric(String str)
    {
        return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        costView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tcost);
        dateEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
        priceEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fuelprice);
        pumpEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fuelpump);
        odometerEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.odometer);
        fconView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fcon);


           priceEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                  //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it
                   if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null))
                        priceEditStr = priceEdit.getText().toString().trim();
                   if(!pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null))
                        pumpEditStr = pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim();

                  if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                  {
                    result = Double.parseDouble(priceEditStr) * Double.parseDouble(pumpEditStr);              
                    costView.setText(" "+result);
                  }

               }
           });

           pumpEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                  //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it
                   if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                        priceEditStr = priceEdit.getText().toString().trim();
                   if(!pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                        pumpEditStr = pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim();


                   if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                      {
                        result = Double.parseDouble(priceEditStr) * Double.parseDouble(pumpEditStr);              
                        costView.setText(" "+result);
                      }

               }
           });







           odometerEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }



               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                  //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it

                   if(!odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                       odmEditStr = odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim();


                  if(!odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                     {
                       resultCon = Double.parseDouble(odmEditStr) - Double.parseDouble(lastOdm) /Double.parseDouble(pumpEditStr);              
                       fconView.setText(" "+ resultCon);
                     }

               }
           });



           cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelBTN);
           cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    /// Create Intent for About  and start activity
                    Intent summaryView=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),summary.class);
                    startActivity(summaryView);
                    }
                });



   //Insert
        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBTN);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                DBAdapter dbAdaptor = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());

                try
                {
                    dbAdaptor.open();
                   // String cursor = dbAdaptor.getLastOdometer();
                    String date = dateEdit.getText().toString();
                    String price = priceEdit.getText().toString();
                    String pump = pumpEdit.getText().toString();
                    String tcost = costView.getText().toString();
                    String odometer = odometerEdit.getText().toString();
                    String fcon = fconView.getText().toString();
                    dbAdaptor.insertLog(date, price, pump, tcost, odometer, fcon);
                    Intent summaryView=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),summary.class);
                    startActivity(summaryView);

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Fuel Log", e.getMessage());
                }
                finally
                {
                    if(dbAdaptor != null)
                        dbAdaptor.close();
                }
            }
        });




















    }
    public void onDOBClicked(View v) {
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getApplicationContext(), new OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                     GregorianCalendar gCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");

            dateEdit.setText(dateFormatter.format(gCalendar.getTime()));

                }
            }, 
            modifiedDoctor.getDobYear(), modifiedDoctor.getDobMonth(), modifiedDoctor.getDobDate());

            dialog.setTitle("Select the date");
            dialog.show();
        }

}
```

Comment: Here are the links of same questions!


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401748/check-if-edittext-input-matches-simpledateformat-android
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764233/validate-date-in-edittext-box

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest show a date picker when edittext is clicked, make that edittext non editable.

Selecting any date should show that date in the edittext. Nowadays in trend.

```
public void onDOBClicked(View v) {


   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(mActivityContext, new OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        setDoctorDOB(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        modifiedDoctor.setDobDate(dayOfMonth);
        modifiedDoctor.setDobMonth(monthOfYear);
        modifiedDoctor.setDobYear(year);
    }
}, year, month, day);

    dialog.setTitle("Select Date of Birthday");
    dialog.show();
}
```

Now on the editText add this.

```
android:editable="false"
android:enabled="false"
android:onClick="onDOBClicked"
```

Comment: I'm not using datepicker

Comment: Yes, I know you aren't using, but better idea to use one, so first to avoid typing, another no date validation, reduces loads of code.

Comment: I've already place android:inputType="date" in code xml.

Comment: I'm kind of lost, because it's my first attempt dealing with android date

Comment: Wait...I will add some more code...

Comment: Check the edit. Clicking on this edittext would show a datepicker, select the date and you are done. Simple ?

Comment: Yes!(: thanks.. but I'm inserting it to the database as a string, is that all right with it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45767/discussion-between-hardik4560-and-chloe)

Comment: what is modifiedDoctor

Comment: that was just my model, I have removed it, u pass the default date.

Comment: there is error in the whole line. 
I've change mActivityContext to getApplicationContext

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45773/discussion-between-hardik4560-and-chloe)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can set the `android:inputType="date"` in xml.

this wont allow to type any other characters in this field. But the validation can be done by either using a `datePicker` or you can use `regex`

Comment: I have already done that

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to refer [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) android to make it easy

create a method to return the extact match

```
public static boolean validateDate( String date )
           {
              return date.matches("\\b[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}\\b");
           }
```

check it returns true if it is not setError on your editText

```
if(!(validateDate(date.getText().toString()))){
            date.setError("Enter Valid date");

        }
```